# Prevent jQuery blur from triggering while being using TAB key

Tags: jquery, iphone, blur

Working on a mobile version of a site with a fixed header. Because iPhones push headers up and while the keyboard is sliding up, then drops back down... I decided to hide it using jQuery.

Working beautifully... except for when you 'tab' through with the next/previous buttons. Then the header will pulsate because the blur event is triggered.

I've posted a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/osifer/VVeL9/3/). I've tried a lot of different solutions but haven't found one that works.

```
$(".input").focus(function () {
    $('header').fadeTo("fast", 0).css('z-index', 1);
})
$('.input').delay(100).blur(function () {
    $('header').fadeTo("fast", 1).css('z-index', 3);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `stop` to your `focus` and a small `delay` before fading in should do:

```
$(".input").focus(function() {
    $('header').stop(true).fadeTo("fast", 0).css('z-index', 1);
});

$('.input').blur(function() {
    $('header').delay(100).fadeTo("fast", 1).css('z-index', 3);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VVeL9/7/

Comment: This works and is pretty clean as well. The only downside is that it will come back if you tab through quickly.

Comment: Works like a charm. Your version was cleaner. Thank you sir.